# Flask deployement on lighttpd and raspberry pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, lighttpd

I'm trying to deploy a hello flask app to a raspberry pi using lighttpd fastCGI.

I followed the instructions on the http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/fastcgi/ to the best of my ability

Here is my flask app (/var/www/demoapp/hello.py)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World From Flask Yeh!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

And here is my .fcgi file (/var/www/demoapp/hello.fcgi)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from yourapplication import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

And here is what I added to my /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

```
fastcgi.server = ("/hello.fcgi" =>
    ((
        "socket" => "/tmp/hello-fcgi.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/var/www/demoapp/hello.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1
    ))
)

alias.url = (
    "/static/" => "/var/www/demoapp/static/",
)
```

I get a 404 Not Found error

By the way what is the /tmp/hello-fcgi.sock where do I get this file

Please help. I'm essentially trying to find a simple way to deploy flask on my raspberry pi web server. I have tried several methods. The fastcgi seemed to be the easiest. If there is an easier way then let me know please.

Thank you

Vincent

Comment: I'm having the same issue... did you find something?

Comment: fast cgi is old. go for wsgi. Gunicorn is your friend. Apache work fine for some projects.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that in your hello.fcgi file, you are importing a module named `yourapplication`, however, the flask application you created is named `hello`.

Try changing this line:

`from yourapplication import app`
to
`from hello import app`

Edit: Also - double check your url when testing - since your `@app.route` is set to the root, you **must** include the trailing slash in your url, eg:

> http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/hello.fcgi/

and not

> http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/hello.fcgi

Answer (score 1):

First, like c_tothe_k said, you need to change `yourapplication` to `hello` in your `hello.fcgi` file.

I found the instructions in the flask documentation to be lacking. It recommends reading this page, and so do I, http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI#Troubleshooting

The bottom of the page has an example lighttpd.conf

I followed a hybrid of the instructions in the Flask documentation and the above page.  I renamed the `.fcgi` file to `.py`, as shown in the Lightty documentation.

You don't have to worry about the .sock file if you follow this approach. It's the old way that lighttpd used to communicate with a FastCGI process, using a UNIX socket. It just needs to be here so the config parser isn't broken.

I used the following in my lighttpd.conf. Your other files look fine otherwise.
(Note, this will put your app under `/hello`, and not `/`.)

```
fastcgi.server = (
    "/hello" =>
    (
        "python-fcgi" =>
        (
         "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.python.socket",
         "bin-path" => "/var/www/demoapp/hello.py",
         "check-local" => "disable",
         "max-procs" => 1,
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is putting config part into `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-fastcgi.conf` instead of `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

I am guessing that file appears there after you run `sudo lighttpd-enable-mod fastcgi`

I also ran `pip3 install flup-py3` to make sure that python3 support is there.